# UIImageView with custom border

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, border

I've a problem with UIImageView with custom border.

how can i make an image like this?

[image]

I add the normal image with bread, and i have this image, the border

[image]

any idea?

thanks

Comment: EDIT: the border seems like it's invisible, but it's just white!!!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use a bucket fill tool to fill the star outer border.
Afterwards, just create a new UIImageView with the original imageView frame and put it on top of the original image using "bringToFront()" method:

```
        let imgView_bread = UIImageView(image: UIImage (named: "bread"))
        imgView_bread.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        self.view.addSubview(imgView_bread);

        let imgView_starBorder = UIImageView(image: UIImage (named: "star_border"))
        imgView_starBorder.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imgView_starBorder.frame = imgView_bread.frame
        self.view.addSubview (imgView_starBorder);
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront (imgView_starBorder);
```